# Remove all lines containing a certain word

Tags: python, string, format

Having a string like this one:

```
AAAA AAAA
BBBB BBBB
CCCC CCCC
DDXD DDDD
EEEE EEEE
FXFF RRRR
```

How could I remove all the lines containing an "X"?

I know that I could do it from a txt file, but I would like to do it directly from the string...

The result must be:

```
AAAA AAAA
BBBB BBBB
CCCC CCCC
EEEE EEEE
```

I tried with:

```
with open('oldfile.txt') as oldfile, open('newfile.txt', 'w') as newfile:
    for line in oldfile:
        if not any(bad_word in line for bad_word in bad_words):
            newfile.write(line)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily accomplish this by using list comprehension. Iterate through your string (split by `\n`) and if a row is spotted without an `X`, then append it to a list.

```
stringRemoval = "AAAA AAAA\nBBBB BBBB\nCCCC CCCC\nDDXD DDDD\nEEEE EEEE\nFXFF RRRR"
cleanString = [line for line in stringRemoval.split('\n') if 'X' not in line]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
with open("file.txt", "w") as f:
    for line in lines:
        if not "X" in line:
            f.write(line)
```